# Usar C em ShellScript

Tags: shell-script, shell

Em Shell podemos utilizar dentro do script outras linguagens como awk e sed, gostaria de saber se seria possível utilizar a linguagem C, e se sim, como.

Comment: Ve se esse link te ajuda: https://www.unix.com/programming/122190-c-program-execute-shell-script.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de um script shell não é possível ter código C nativo, como o caso que você mencionou do `sed` e do `awk`. Acho que é válido pensar que em um shell script você consegue fazer tudo que conseguiria fazer direto no terminal. Para o C, você precisa de um código próprio e um compilador e, portanto, não dá pra rodar direto no .sh

Contudo, você pode fazer chamadas pra um script C externo se ele já estiver compilado, por exemplo

hello_world.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    printf("hello world!\n");
}
```

hello.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./hello_world
```

depois de compilar o C (`gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world`), rode o `.sh` e a saída vai ser

> hello world!